# Automatic line break inside multicolumn table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I'm trying to create a table as shown below. I'm not sure why my code makes the "Sample ID" column as wide as the "Composition" column even though they have a different setting in the `multicolumn{}{this}{}` line. Is there a way to control the width in an easier way or am I just too blind to see the mistake I made somewhere?

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{6cm}|p{1cm}|} 
\multicolumn{2}{p{5cm}}{\textbf{Date:}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Donor ID:}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{} \\
\multicolumn{2}{p{5cm}}{\textbf{ }} & 
\multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}}{\textbf{ }}\\
\multicolumn{2}{p{5cm}}{\textbf{Serial index:}} & \multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}}{\textbf{ }} \\
\multicolumn{2}{p{5cm}}{\textbf{ }} & 
\multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}}{\textbf{ }}\\
\hline 
\textbf{Solution} & \textbf{Sample ID} & \textbf{Composition} & 
\textbf{Init} \\ \hline 
1 & \underbar{WB - Human Whole Blood} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{6cm}|}{The WB is gently mixed in the vacutainer and poured into a plastic beaker before it is collected in an appropriate sized syringe} &  \\ \hline 
2 & \underbar{Ref WB} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{6cm}|}{Approx. 1 mL HWB is collected for reference measurements on the flow cytometer and an ABL90} & \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Update:
The code is updated due to a fine adjustment that was necessary. A new image is uploaded as well to show the problem. I want cell (2,2) to wrap the text, but i doesn't seem like `\underline` allows that operation? any suggestions?

[image: Original situation]

[image: New situation]

Comment: why have you got any `\multicolumn` here at all in the body of the table??, there are no spanning entries)

Comment: I've tried several things and i just thought that i could control the width more precisely with multicolumn. I just found out that it wasn't capable of wrapping the underlined text in cell (2,2). I just worked around that and wrote the name in two underlines. Prob not the best solution, but works for my purpose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:**

like this (considering your comment below answer)?

[image]

it is obtained by use of `tabularx` table environment, macros `\thead` and `\makegapedcells` from `makcell` package and appropriate selection of columns type. for underlined text in second column's cells is used `\ul{...}` instead of `\underbar{...}` (which not enable to break lines) from package `soul` which enales to brak text in cells. for values with measure i suggest to use `\siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\newcommand\mcl[1]{\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{soul}    % <---
\usepackage{siunitx} % <---

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|l|X|c|}
\mcl{Date:}         &   \mcl{Donor ID:}                             \\[2ex]
\mcl{Serial index:} &   \mcl{}                                      \\[2ex]
    \hline
\thead{Solution}    & \thead{Sample ID}
                            & \thead{Composition}   & \thead{Init}  \\
    \hline
1   & \ul{WB - Human Whole Blood} % <---
                & The WB is gently mixed in the vacutainer and poured into a plastic beaker before it is collected in an appropriate sized syringe
                            &                                       \\
    \hline
2   & \ul{Ref WB} 
                & Approx. \SI{1}{mL} HWB is collected for reference measurements on the flow cytometer and an ABL90
                            &                                       \\
\hline
3   & \ul{WB - Human Whole Blood and more stuff}
                & Approx. \SI{1}{mL} % <---
                  HWB is collected for reference measurements on the flow cytometer and an ABL90
                            &                                       \\
   \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is more or less exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I think the solution you suggest is neater, but I kinda still have a problem when the string "WB - Human Whole Blood" gets longer, e.g. "WB - Human Whole Blood and more stuff". This will just compress the Composition column. Are you experiencing something similar? It should just wrap the text automatically.

Comment: than you should allowed to break cells' contents n this column. this is possible with use `\ul{...}˙` macro from soul package. see edited answer.